# Running a program with argument sent from command line

Tags: java, command-line, arraylist

I need my program to take a String argument and split the characters up.
I then want to add these individual characters to an ArrayList and print out the list with the individual characters underneath each other
Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter argument:");
        String input = br.readLine();
        String value = "";

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
            value = "" + input.charAt(i);
            al.add(value);
        }

        Iterator it = al.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
            it.remove();
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

The argument should come from the command line, for example:
java myApp Lesley

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using user input not command line args in above program

Comment: the argument "Lesley" can be found in `args[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        String input = String.valueOf(args[0]);//assuming there will always be an input from command line
        String value = "";

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
            value = "" + input.charAt(i);
            al.add(value);
        }

        Iterator it = al.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
            it.remove();
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

try this

Comment: I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i run the following command line: java (the destination to my file) Armandt ... any suggestions ?? am i invoking it wrong ?

Comment: path till ur .class file? it has to be it. or the simple way is to go to clas path(where your .class file is generated after compiling this code) and run java <className> Armandt from there

Comment: C:Documents and settings\ArrA\Prac2\build\classes\prac2\Main

Comment: check if class file is present under that path, then, run set CLASSPATH="C:\Documents and settings\ArrA\Prac2\build\classes\prac2\" and directly run following
java Main Armandt

Answer (score 0):

those parameters are stored in the `String[] args` array
like VD wrote... but you should check your args array if there are parameters

```
If (args.length != 0) {
    do something
}
```

Edit:
if you use the commandline to run your program you have to compile it first with

```
javac pathtofile
```

than you can use

```
java pathtofile
```

Comment: I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i run the following command line: java (the destination to my file) Armandt ... any suggestions ?? am i invoking it wrong ?

Comment: did you compile your .java?
javac path/to/your/file
after that 
java path/to/your/file

Answer (score 0):

Why you make it so difficult?

```
if(input.contains("java myApp Lesley"){
window.window();                       //new class where u create the window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line parameters are passed to the main method via its parameter `String[] args`.
Since that is not always obvious to the one calling your program, its good style to give a hint if the parameters are missing. For example:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Usage: myApp <Name>");
}
else {
    // your code here using args[0]
}
```

If you are using more than one command line parameter, change the check accordingly.